# Boids Allow Land Simulation Issues

Tags: particles, physics

I am trying to create a simple 'Rat Swarm' simulation, my problem is when the boids are set to allow land [image]

simulation is starting to freak out when leading the particles below 0 -Z axis

I am clueless regarding what I might do wrong so please if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

attaching a .blend file as an example + gif of the issue[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i am a solution oriented person. Hope you are too.

Why don't you just move it all above zero?

i tried...and it worked.

[image]

Comment: Nice Try :p   I have a scene that I need to match the simulation to and not the other way around, Obviously if necessary I will, but I would like to know if this is a Blender limitation or an error on my side